# Replace space with "-"?

Tags: jquery, html

Please check for me this script below, I don't know why it does not run.
Check now :

```
<script>
 $("#categories li a").each(function() {

   var hreflink = (/[^/]*$/.exec(decodeURIComponent(this.href)));
   //var realhref = hreflink.replace(/\s/g, '_');
        $(this).attr("href", "#" + hreflink);
  });

</script>
```

Explain: I want replace all links with `"category"` (catch from links)
Example:

I have link like :

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/new%20link">New Link</a>
```

After replace I have only:

```
<a href="#new-link">New Link</a>
```

I decode url and then replace but replace may has problems.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: `%20` is the code for `[space]` not `-`

Comment: You mean the decoding does not append to space?

Comment: my mistake I didn't see the replace code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec function returns an array, you need to get the first item in the array

```
$("#categories li a").attr('href', function (_, href) {
    var hreflink = (/[^/]*$/.exec(decodeURIComponent(href)))[0];
    return hreflink.replace(/\s/g, '_');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7P78H/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
.replace(/\s/g,"-");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vYnxm/25/)

Comment: I tried. But it does not run. You can run my code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7P78H/4/ Although I know I got it late! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    href = href.replace(/%20/g,"-");
    href = href.replace(/ /g,"-");
    href = href.split("/").pop();
    $(this).attr("href","#"+href);
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A9FC8/1)